# Как прописать в коде, какую спецификацию javascript я использую?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, passenger

Использую node js на сервере (с помощью) Passenger.
Установил версию 9.10.1
Приложение запускается, но все попытки использовать синтаксис ES6 ведут к ошибкам. Даже такая простая вещь, как использование `` - ругается, якобы (SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL). Вопрос:
Может есть какое то правило, которое можно прописать перед всем кодом, указывающее, что мы сейчас будем использовать такую то версию EcmaScript?

А ещё вот такую ошибку выдаёт:

"nodejs_app/www/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:7

const Schema = require('./schema');
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode."

Хотя версия ноды 9.10.1!

Comment: _Может есть какое то правило, которое можно прописать перед всем кодом, указывающее, что мы сейчас будем использовать такую то версию EcmaScript?_ - нет.

Comment: Подозреваю, passenger тащит с собой свою ноду или находит где-то старую

Comment: А для очистки совести, что выведет `console.log(process.version)`?